# How to View the OS image Files such as .raw or .bin files any command available in Linux or QNX?

Tags: image, operating-system, qnx

I have created a a OS image File using mketfs  in qnx and the final image is in .raw format.. Is there any way to view the .raw files.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a dumpifs in your development system which can pick bits of info out of an image file system.   I don't know about .raw; it has been a while....